# Pandas: Getting the distance to the row used to fill the missing/na values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe and I am trying to get the distance to the row which was used to fill a row of `nan` values in the same dataframe.

To elaborate, say I have the following dataframe (`df`) that contains 2 rows of `nan` values,

```
     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Using the forward fill `df.fillna(method='ffill')`, I get the following dataframe,

```
     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

I would like to have another column (let's call it `Proximity`) in the dataframe that contains the distance  to the row from which it filled its nan values, in this example, it should be,

```
     A    B    C  Proximity
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  2.0
```

Row 2's Proximity is 1, since it used the row above it to fill its own `nan` values.

Row 3's Proximity is 2, since it used the row above it by two levels to fill its own `nan` values.

Row 1 is already filled, therefore, the row it used to fill its own `nan` values is zero because it doesn't have any `nan` values.

Is there a way I can compute that `Proximity` column efficiently ?

By efficiently, I mean without using `for` loops.

Comment: proximity can vary column by column.  are you certain a row will either be all NaN or None?

Comment: Good point! yes, we can assume that a certain row is either all NaNs or none; otherwise, perhaps it's possible to have proximity per column ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.cumsum()` so that each `notnull` block value gets a unique 'id', `.groupby()` the result and use `.cumcount()`, which assigns `0` to all `notnull` values and consecutive counts to `null` values::

```
df['proximity'] = df.groupby(df.notnull().all(axis=1).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df.loc[np.random.choice(np.arange(100), 50)] = np.nan
```

Results in:

```
      A    B    C  proximity
0   5.0  5.0  3.0          0
1   2.0  3.0  1.0          0
2   0.0  2.0  4.0          0
3   NaN  NaN  NaN          1
4   NaN  NaN  NaN          2
5   5.0  3.0  5.0          0
6   NaN  NaN  NaN          1
7   6.0  7.0  8.0          0
8   1.0  5.0  2.0          0
9   NaN  NaN  NaN          1
10  5.0  9.0  6.0          0
11  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
12  7.0  8.0  8.0          0
13  7.0  7.0  5.0          0
14  4.0  9.0  5.0          0
15  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
16  2.0  9.0  8.0          0
17  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
18  NaN  NaN  NaN          2
19  8.0  6.0  7.0          0
20  8.0  2.0  0.0          0
21  1.0  3.0  1.0          0
22  0.0  3.0  9.0          0
23  8.0  3.0  9.0          0
24  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
25  9.0  3.0  6.0          0
26  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
27  9.0  0.0  8.0          0
28  0.0  4.0  9.0          0
29  8.0  8.0  3.0          0
..  ...  ...  ...        ...
70  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
71  NaN  NaN  NaN          2
72  4.0  9.0  4.0          0
73  8.0  2.0  6.0          0
74  2.0  8.0  2.0          0
75  3.0  3.0  6.0          0
76  0.0  9.0  1.0          0
77  8.0  0.0  8.0          0
78  3.0  0.0  6.0          0
79  2.0  4.0  6.0          0
80  4.0  2.0  4.0          0
81  1.0  5.0  2.0          0
82  5.0  4.0  2.0          0
83  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
84  NaN  NaN  NaN          2
85  1.0  2.0  8.0          0
86  3.0  2.0  8.0          0
87  4.0  1.0  2.0          0
88  2.0  8.0  0.0          0
89  2.0  2.0  6.0          0
90  7.0  5.0  9.0          0
91  0.0  6.0  8.0          0
92  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
93  9.0  5.0  8.0          0
94  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
95  NaN  NaN  NaN          2
96  NaN  NaN  NaN          3
97  1.0  4.0  2.0          0
98  NaN  NaN  NaN          1
99  7.0  2.0  5.0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
def prox(series):
    groupby_idx = series.notnull().cumsum()
    groupby = series.groupby(groupby_idx)
    return groupby.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(len(x)))).values

prox(df1.A)

array([0, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

then assign to df1:

```
df1['Proximity'] = prox(df1.A)

print df1.ffill()

     A    B    C  Proximity
0  0.0  0.0  0.0          0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0          0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0          1
3  1.0  2.0  3.0          2
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, np.nan, np.nan], "B": [2, np.nan, np.nan]})

In[2]: df.ix[df.B.isnull(), 'distance'] = 1

In[3]: df.distance = df.distance.cumsum()

In[4]: df
Out[4]: 
     A    B  distance
0  1.0  2.0       NaN
1  NaN  NaN       1.0
2  NaN  NaN       2.0
```